# How can I migrate a git repo from Windows to Linux? (CRLF - LF issue)

Tags: git, newline, lf

I started a git repository on a Windows machine, and then I changed to a Linux machine. Everything is working fine, but every time I commit, I get the warning `warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in [file]`.
I know I can set auto conversion off but, is there a command to convert all line endings into the Linux's form?
I am not going to work with this project in Windows any more.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a dos2unix command.

Comment: Ok, this was it, if you make it an answer I'll accept it. Or vote it for closing if it's something too simple. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a dos2unix command which will change a text file from dos format (using CR LF) to unix format (using just LF).  Using that, you can easily do something like

```
dos2unix *.c *.h
```